# Torah service on Hoshana Rabba

Tags: minhag, torah-service, nusach-ashkenaz, hoshana-rabbah

My old Ashkenazi *machzor* says that the *Torah* scroll should be removed from the Ark on *Hoshana Rabba* just as on the Shabbat. Nevertheless, I find a few points unclear, while I make some reasonable assumptions:

- I assume that those who say *Ein kamokhah* on Shabbat should say it.
- Those who say the [13 attributes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Attributes_of_Mercy) with the *Ribono shel olam* omit that on Shabbat, so I assume here as well.
- I suppose those who say *Shema* should say it.
- As *Al hakol* is said on Shabbat, I assume it should be said.
- I have no clue whether the two *Yekum purkan* and the *Mishebeirakh* for Shabbat are said or not.
- I don't know whether Psalm [24](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2624.htm) or [29](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2629.htm) is said eventually.

I have seen multiple practices, so I would be glad if you knew some sources that explicitly discuss the removal of the *Torah* scroll on *Hoshana Rabba* from an Ashkenazi perspective.

Comment: It doesn't say "as on Yom Tov"?

Comment: @DoubleAA My Schlesinger machzor says explicitly Shabbat.

Comment: (Just got back from shul). No yekum, yes to Ein kamocha, 13 attributes through va'ani tefilati, sh'ma (kadosh vnora), 24 not 29. As per Artscroll sukkot machzor.

Comment: And also veyaazor instead of vesigaleh

Comment: שערי אפרים is a good source for Ashkenazic Torah-service halacha. I recommend checking it if you haven't.

Comment: @Heshy what you mean to say is the full Al Hakol is recited like on Yom Tov. Only when it isn't is ותגלה the conclusion of the processional before calling up the Kohein.

Comment: @msh210 Should you have something in mind, I'd highly appreciate if you could write an answer based on that.

Comment: (re your comment to me) No, I haven't had time to check it, myself.

Comment: @rosends I've just checked last year's luach, which says (without reference, but confirmed by a Schlesinger siddur): _After Halleil Ein kamokhah. At the removal of the Torah the Ribono shel olam of Rosh hashanah and Veyaazor etc._